# Qualtrics - setEmbeddedData

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm pretty new to javascript, and I'm just trying to do some simple stuff as practice to learn.

I've created two embedded data fields in the survey flow and named them "A1" and "A2." In A1 I have assigned a value in the survey flow but I'm trying to set the value of A2 in the javascript of a question.

[Survey Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJTVk.png)

In question 2's javascript I've put a setEmbeddedData statement that isn't working. I'm piping in the choice text in the question from A2 and nothing is coming in.

[This is what I've used in the question's javascript...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cD0I.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. setEmbeddedData() doesn't work with Simple layout.
2. When you use setEmbeddedData(), you can't pipe the value set until the next survey page